# Not able to click() on newly added account number from a account list on the page

Tags: selenium-webdriver, java, xpath

A new account is created using selenium script and a message appears that "Account is created successfully : <***12345>"

After this, Account page is displayed where all the accounts are available. And newly created account (***12345) is also listed but in the middle of table somewhere. Even sorting does not bring this account at the top so that It can be picked up after sorting.

Now I need to select this account to perform further operations on it. Currently when I click the account on 'accounts' page based on x-path provided, older account can be clicked. But since new account is created during script execution only, how can I click on this account from the account table.

I am thinking of grabbing account no. from the message box and storing in a variable but not able to write a x-path which uses this variable to click on newly added account only during execution.

Please provide your input?

Comment: Welcome. It would be helpful to add images of your webpage, a link to it if you can, what your code looks like that perfoms this test/action, what does the DOM look like?

Comment: it would be great if you can share the XPath of the old account and the one which you are trying. By reading this, I can assume it is straightforward that you just have to build the XPath with dynamic value. There is a similar question someone asked yesterday.Please search there

Comment: Thanks for the input. I troubleshooted this issue as below:

Answer (score 0):

> I am thinking of grabbing account no. from the message box and storing in a variable but not able to write a x-path which uses this variable to click on newly added account only during execution.

Psuedo-Code:

```
accountPage.aCreateNew.click();
var newAccountId = messageModal.divMessage.getText();
driver.findElement(By.Xpath("//a[contains(@href, '" + newAccountId + "')).click();
```

Comment: Thanks for the direction. I was able to sort out issue as below:

Comment: Thanks for the direction. I was able to sort out issue as below:                                        
                                                                                                                                           
String accountDetails = getDriver().findElement(By.xpath)).getText();                               String accountNumber = myNumbers.toString();                                                                                   
getDriver().findElement(By.xpath("//*[normalize-space(text())='"+accountNumber+"']")).click();